# Dynamic div's using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

**JavaScript**

```
var i = 0;

function creatediv() {
    i++;

    var newelement = document.createElement('div');
    newelement.setAttribute('id', i);

    newelement.style.color = 'FFCC66';
    newelement.style.background = 'FFCC66';
    newelement.style.width = '500px';
    newelement.style.height = '100px';

    var parentelement = document.getElementById('presentdiv');
    parentelement.appendChild(newelement);
    var lastchild = parentelement.lastChild;
    parentelement.insertBefore(lastchild, parentelement);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="presentdiv">
    <script>
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

            creatediv(i);

        }
    </script>
</div>
```

I want to create multiple dynamic div's using JavaScript. I use a for loop and `creatediv()` function, but in this code, only one div is created dynamically when I run my full code.

Comment: `parentelement.insertBefore(lastchild, parentelement);` what is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
//var i = 0; No need

function creatediv(i) { //Add i as a parameter
    //i++; No need

    var newelement = document.createElement('div');
    newelement.setAttribute('id', i);

    newelement.style.color = '#FFCC66'; // # is required to show color
    newelement.style.background = '#FFCC66'; // # is required to show color
    newelement.style.width = '500px';
    newelement.style.height = '100px';

    var parentelement = document.getElementById('presentdiv');
    parentelement.appendChild(newelement);

//What is the purpose of lines below?
    //var lastchild = parentelement.lastChild;  
    //parentelement.insertBefore(lastchild, parentelement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've some errors in ur code.
To start, you sent  `creatediv(i);`  and 'i' is not declared in the function `function creatediv() { }`

You are increasing `i`, inside the iterator, but the iterator is increasing itself too  `for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {`

While you fix that errors, i will try to prepare a piece of code for you

Comment: if the _only_ issue with this code is `i`, it should insert 6 divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function create()
            {
                var ar = [], i;

                for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
                {
                    ar[i] = function()
                    {
                        var newElem = document.createElement('div');
                        newElem.setAttribute('id', i);

                        newElem.style.color = 'FFCC66';
                        newElem.style.background = 'FFCC66';
                        newElem.style.width = '500px';
                        newElem.style.height = '100px';

                        var parent = document.getElementById('presentdiv');
                        parent.appendChild(newElem);
                    };
                }

                return ar;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="presentdiv">
            <script>
                var a = create();

                for( var i=0; i<3; i++ )
                {
                    a[i]();
                }
            </script>
        </div>

        <script>

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have used closures, he was looping the wrong way, many() is just a name that i gave but it is the one that helps loop to make many functions..

Comment: I was just asking because `many()` doesn't seem to be used anywhere in the code :)

Comment: ah, yes, the ar[i] is private function, i made mistake..though many() could have taken code that was in the private function. thank you..

Answer (score -1):

First I would advise of using jQuery or something similar to do DOM manipulation, this will avoid browser compatibility problems.

Secondly, you have a problem of scope and understanding.
Your function is not using the argument that you give in the loop.
You try to increase twice the iterator.
You try to increase the iterator inside the function which don't use the same scope (so it doesn't know the `i` that you define in the loop).
You created a global variable `i`.
`<script></script>` tag shouldn't be in the middle of the html. `<head></head>` or beginning (or ends) of `<body></body>` tag is a way better idea.

The corrected code (without jQuery) will be:

```
function creatediv(a) {
    var newelement = document.createElement('div');
    newelement.setAttribute('id', a);

    newelement.style.color = 'FFCC66';
    newelement.style.background = 'FFCC66';
    newelement.style.width = '500px';
    newelement.style.height = '100px';

    var parentelement = document.getElementById('presentdiv');
    parentelement.appendChild(newelement);
}

function runloop() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        creatediv(i);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="runloop()">
     <div id="presentdiv"></div>
</body>
```

And finally, you should make sure that the DOM is ready before beginning DOM Manipulation. Here again jQuery will help you.

I hope this will help.

**EDIT**
You can play with this http://jsfiddle.net/LknaZ/4/

**EDIT2**
Now this code make sure that the DOM is ready

Comment: This code does not add any div to the `#presentdiv`. The reason behind is that when the script script block executes, the `#presentdiv` isn't present in the page.

Comment: That's why I said that he should make sure that the DOM is ready.

Comment: If you got your answer, can you mark your question as resolved ?